# Frequency Response Signal plotted numerically?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to plot the frequency response signal of a filter, however I do not quite understand its implementation. Would there be a way to plot the frequency response signal numerically? As in generating multiples signals with ranging frequencies and plot how much of the signal was attenuated from there? I do not have a background in signal preprocessing.

In particular, the filter for which I wish to plot the FRS is : https://github.com/PIA-Group/BioSPPy/blob/7696d682dc3aafc898cd9161f946ea87db4fed7f/biosppy/signals/ecg.py#L29

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far

Comment: Well I haven't tried anything yet. I'm searching for ways to do this easily. Since I am unfamiliar with signal processing, whatever I try is likely to be incorrect.